# Comparing a string of quiz answers to questions

Tags: c++, string

I have a C++ test question that asks us to write a program that:
1) asks the user to input a string of answers a,b,c, and d: (Example: ACDBDA)
2) asks he user to input a string that is the answer key: (example DBADCD) (we also need to put in something to make sure the length of the answer key is the same as the answers, but that is no biggie)
3) prints the percentage of input answers that were correct, ie match up with the answer key.

Most of this isn't too bad, but I'm not sure how to go about comparing the two strings to see how they differ. Is there any way to get a variable equal to one of the characters in the string which could then be compared with a variable representing the character in the same place as the other string? That's the only way that comes to mind for me. I'm not really looking for a specific code or someone to do it for me, just need some pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Ok, so I've made some progress on this and I think I am close. The problem now is that I'm getting "Expression must be of class type" error on the commented lines. I think the issue is in the way I am passing my parameters but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it :(. I've google'd several parameter passing articles but none seem to speak to passing a parameter then getting it's length or comparing it as I do in the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string getAnswers(string answers)
{

    cout << "What are your answers to this questionless quiz? BE WARY OF CHOOSING           INCORRECTLY\n:";
    cin >> answers;
    return answers;
}

string getKey(string key)
{
    cout << "Just kidding. What are the answers? \n:";
    cin >> key;
    return key;
}

double getPercentage(double percentage)
{
    int total;
    int correct;
    getAnswers();
    getKey();
    total = getAnswers.size();      // "error: expression must have class type"
    for (i=0; i>total; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        if (getAnswers.at(j) = getKey.at(j))    // "error: expression must have     class type" (for both getAnswers and getKey)
            correct++;
            j++;
    }
    percentage = (correct/total) * 100;
}

int main()
{
    getAnswers();
    getKey();
    cout << getPercentage(answers, key);        //Also I'm really not sure how to get the parameters from previous functions into this one here. Maybe I shoudln't even add parameters and just show the function?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also to clarify, we're not supposed to have any actual quiz format or questions. It's literally enter answers, enter key, show percentage correct.

Comment: "Is there any way to get a variable equal to one of the characters in the string which could then be compared with a variable representing the character in the same place as the other string? That's the only way that comes to mind for me." Yep, it looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: `std::string` has an index operator that accesses single characters. You can use that in a loop. E.g. `str[3]` would access the fourth character in the string (because the lowest index is zero).